# Calling all model instances from cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that have model called Project. I need to go through all the projects every day and call method "project_due?".

I guess I would need to use Whenever gem to create cron job, but I am lost in next step: what is the correct way to access the model instances?

Edit: model code, it is actually quite simple:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def need_new_forecast?
      d = self.forecasts.last.date_stamp || Date.today
      return Date.today.beginning_of_week > d.beginning_of_week
  end
end
```

I need to go through all Projects every day to check which project needs new forecast (then I will email user and so forth). The code is simplified, there are other cases in my app: things like daily/monthly/quarterly forecasts

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. can you try adding some example? and sharing some of your models may be related to this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cron to invoke a rake task. Inside the rake task you can visit your model as usual.